# Xamarin.Forms CollectionView API not tappable with SelectionChangedCommand

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView that has a SelectionChangedCommand property. I would like to allow the cell to navigate to a different page on **TAP**. Instead, when I tap on the cell nothing happens. If I hold my finger down on the cell and move it in any direction the intended action fires.

**View:**

```
<views:CollectionViewExt
                         HeightRequest="170" 
                         WidthRequest="200" 
                         SelectionMode="Single"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SlectedItem}"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"
                         BackgroundColor="Green"
                         SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}">
```

**ViewModel:**

```
   public TrackingItem SlectedItem { get; set; }
   public ICommand ItemSelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new SingleTapCommand<Item>(async e =>
            {
                SlectedItem = e; // this is to reset the selected item.
                await DifferentPage();
            });
        }
    }
```

Again, this works and navigates to 'DifferentPage' with a very hard, slow, long, swipe ( wouldn't even consider it a tap) as it is more like a swipe. When I would like for it to navigate to 'DifferentPage' on Tap.

Can anyone assist me in solving this? Has anyone experienced the same issue?

This has been tested on all iOS platforms.

Comment: what is `CollectionViewExt`?  Have you tested this with a vanilla `CollectionView`?

Comment: @Jason Yes, I have tested with vanilla CollectionView as well. Same thing no different.

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a demo and the tap command works well on my side. I will share my codes below and hope you can get some idea from there:

I think there are some point you need to check:

1. the code of navigating to `DifferentPage`
2. the `SingleTapCommand`

In code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel vm = new viewModel();
        vm.navigation = Navigation;
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}

public class viewModel {

    public INavigation navigation;

    public ICommand ItemSelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async e =>
            {
                // this is to reset the selected item.
                await navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
            });
        }
    }

    public viewModel() { 
        
    }
}
```

In Xaml:

```
<CollectionView BackgroundColor="Green"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}">
    
    <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
            <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
            <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Jack Hua . Although your code & logic makes sense and in theory should work as expected, I am still getting the same results - onSwipe it calls PushAsync, onTap it does nothing. I will look into creating a ticket w/ Xamarin. I will come back to this thread with any information I receive. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you can share your solution here once you solved.